# SQL Query to Select Prevailing Wind Direction by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2012

I have a table in a SQL Server 2012 database that contains weather data (2 minute intervals).

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
 (
     [SampleDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
     [Unit ID] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
     [WS Avg 2min] [float] NULL,
     [WD Avg 2min] [float] NULL,
     [WGS 10min] [float] NULL,
     [WGD 10min] [float] NULL,
     [Air Temp] [float] NULL,
     [Rel Humidity] [float] NULL,
     [Dew Point] [float] NULL,
     [Pyranometer] [float] NULL,
     [Quantum] [float] NULL,
     [Air Pressure] [float] NULL,
     [Snow Level] [float] NULL,
     [Rainfall] [float] NULL,
     [PW Current] [varchar](10) NULL,
     [Visibility] [float] NULL,
     [CBase 1] [float] NULL,
     [CBase 2] [float] NULL,
     [CBase 3] [float] NULL,
     [Vert Vis] [float] NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am trying to get the prevailing wind direction for each day in a month. So basically a count of the directions for each day, returning the max count.
With this query I'm close (from MS Access):

```
SELECT 
    Day([SampleDateTime]) AS [Date], 
    Round([WD Avg 2min],0) AS  WindDir,
    Count(Round([WD Avg 2min],0)) AS [Count]
FROM 
    WeatherData
WHERE 
    (((Year([SampleDateTime]) * 12 + DatePart("m", [SampleDateTime])) = Year(Date()) * 12 + DatePart("m", Date()) - 0))
GROUP BY 
    Day([SampleDateTime]), Round([WD Avg 2min],0)
ORDER BY 
    Day([SampleDateTime]), Count(Round([WD Avg 2min],0)) DESC;
```

I get this result

```
Date   WindDir  Count
1      74       45
1      342      11
1      331      11
1      333      11
1      338      10
2      48       20
2      45       20
2      42       20
2      50       17
```

I can't seem to get the query to return the same result, but with only the Max "Count" for each Date like this

```
Date   WindDir  Count
1      74       45
2      48       20
```

Advice?

Comment: You should provide some input data and desire output. I can see you have a result but not sure what is wrong with that or what is the result you expect

Comment: Just a suggestion, wont be better if you group wind by similar direction. Like [0..9][[10..19] ....[350..359] ? In your sample data day 1 seem to have more wind going to 335ish.

Comment: Yes, eventually I'd like to add grouping by cardinal direction (N, NE, E, etc), but I'm trying to work through this one step at a time and learn as I go.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im going to guess your first query is right and want to reduce to second result.

Using CTE  [**Using Common Table Expressions**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb660/2)

```
WITH month_direction as (
    SELECT 
        Day([SampleDateTime]) AS [Date], 
        Round([WD Avg 2min],0) AS  WindDir,
        Count(Round([WD Avg 2min],0)) AS [Count]
    FROM 
        WeatherData
    WHERE 
        (((Year([SampleDateTime]) * 12 + DatePart("m", [SampleDateTime])) = Year(Date()) * 12 + DatePart("m", Date()) - 0))
    GROUP BY 
        Day([SampleDateTime]), Round([WD Avg 2min],0)
    ORDER BY 
        Day([SampleDateTime]), Count(Round([WD Avg 2min],0)) DESC
),
max_count as (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY Count desc) as rnum
    FROM month_direction 
)
SELECT *
FROM max_count 
WHERE rnum = 1
```